# How do I create a conditional directive in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to define a directive in Angular which takes a DOM like this:

```
<example-directive href="{{ foo }}"><img src="{{ bar }}"></example-directive>
```

... and transforms it to ...

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/FOO_VALUE"><img src="BAR_VALUE"></a>
```

... but *only* if the href is defined.  If `{{ foo }}` is empty, it should transform to

```
<img src="BAR_VALUE">
```

It also needs to respond appropriately when the value of `{{ foo }}` and `{{ bar }}` changes.  I can't figure out the documentation sufficiently to manage it.  How do you do it?

Comment: `href="{{ foo }}"` should be href="foo".

Comment: Why?  I actually want the value to be something like "http://www.test.com/{{ foo }}".  Is that a bad idea?

Comment: Without writing a probably very complicated compile function, I think you'll at least need a common wrapper element like a `span` or similar (for the final output).

Answer (score 1):

Since the conditional show/hide doesn't work for you, what you need is variable templates within the same directive: https://coderwall.com/p/mgtrkg

This way you will have one directive and you will select between two templates depending on the existence or not of the `href`.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Ok I misunderstood the problem. See if i got it right:
I would have two css classes:

```
.vis { display: normal; }
.hid { display : none; }
```

Then your directive could have a html like this

```
<span ng-show="foo != ''"><a href="{{ foo }}"><img src="{{ bar }}" /></a></span>
<span ng-show="foo == ''"><img src="{{ bar }}" /></span>
```

It's a bit of a hacky workaround because of the nature of your html (deleting only a wrapping element makes it tricky), but it should work.

Comment: That doesn't actually address the problem.  The `img` href is `BAR_VALUE` in both cases.  It's only if `{{ foo }}` isn't defined that the wrapping `<a>` tag doesn't appear.

Comment: @ChrisB. sorry i misunderstood the problem but I think i got it now.

Comment: Yes, I could have used ng-hide and ng-show.  But in my real world example, the contents of the `<a>` tag is a lot more complicated, and I don't want to define it twice in the document.

Comment: @ChrisB. other than that I can only think to declare the html of the directive without the wrapping `<a>` and dynamically create it at link time, or even have two directives, the parent one applying the logic above, so that if `foo == ''` it simply wraps/passes through to the inner directive.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a need to use a directive here. Just use `ngIf`:

```
<a ng-if="foo != ''" href="{{foo}}"><img src="{{ bar }}"></a>
<img ng-if="foo == ''" src="{{ bar }}">
```

`ngIf` is a newer directive. Check for the supporting versions.

Comment: My code is a simplified example.  The real content of the link is more complicated, and I really don't want to duplicate it twice.